# Burninate xda tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

So far only 6 questions are asked with this tag and also there is also no description or wiki available for this tag. AFAIK [xda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xda) points to XDA forums which provides support for custom ROM development for Android Devices and they have their own forums for discussion. So according to me this tag should be removed.

Comment: Only 6 questions... That's hardly a burnination. These could simply be edited out, if deemed necessary.

Comment: We need an Environmental Impact Committee set up

Comment: @Cerbrus should we edit it out?

Comment: I miss how this tag meets the [criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) as explained in the [wiki of burninate request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info)

Comment: @VivekMishra: I don't know.

Comment: @rene as no wiki is available for this tag, and according to what I think this tag is for, I think it meets the criteria

Comment: I fail to see how a tag *about a forum*, is even desired... BTW, even without it, all questions tagged with it are off topic, or plain bad (like waffles with jelly bad), so this will end a no-edits burnination.

Comment: @yellowantphil thats what I unerstood from those questions that they are probably related to the website and not mobile phone

Answer (score 5):

Sooo…let me get this straight. You suggest that the tag be burninated for the following reasons:

1. It only has 6 questions.
2. There is no description or wiki for it.
3. Other places on the Internet exist where the technology covered by that tag can be discussed.

Literally ***none*** of those are reasons for a tag to be burninated.

The quantity of questions belonging to a tag is almost entirely meaningless when determining whether a tag is useful or not. All that tells you is that Stack Overflow is not a popular place to ask questions about XDA.

That the tag lacks a description or a wiki just means that someone hasn't created it yet. You could be that person. Or no one could, and the tag would go on serving the humble purpose of categorizing questions until someone *does* create a excerpt and wiki. Neither of these things are *required* for a tag, they're just nice to have. Their absence doesn't make the tag bad, or even problematic.

As for your third reason, I don't even know what to say. Stack Overflow doesn't have the exclusive on any technology that I know of, so pretty much everything that you can ask about here can also be asked about somewhere else. Let's not burninate the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag because Microsoft has discussion forums of their own. (On second thought, aren't there official Android discussion forums? Maybe we get rid of the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag!)

Comment: but that thing is also not related to programming to a much extent as far as I know and moreover c# is a programming language while xda is a community

Comment: Not forgetting that all the questions on this tag are bad or off topic (there were 6 questions, now 4, 1 already closed, 2 on the track, all downvoted).

Comment: I was answering the question as asked. If you have more compelling justifications to burninate the tag, edit them into the question, don't leave comments here.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) given by @rene:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
>   And is it unambiguous?

If I google XDA, I have almost only answers related to that technologies; XDA can refer to an old series of Microsoft phones discontinued. So I think this point is good.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It's clearly about developing.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

It's about quite a low level development on Android, so not everyone developing for Android will be able to answer questions about it. I think still this tag should at least always be used with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) since it's a low attractive tag (at least at the moment).

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

As said in the first point, it seems that won't be a problem.

At worst we may rename it to [android-xda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-xda) to not have to do it later on if something else called 'XDA' comes out.

Comment: so I think misjudged xda with this http://www.xda-developers.com/. According to what you have described it is perfectly on topic and a valid tag. Although it's wiki should be added to avoid confusions